# python read excel file and save N txt files with title and content from excel

Tags: python, loops, file

I have excel file with 3 columns:

```
 index  |   name  | surname
 0      |   John  | White
 2      |   Bill  | Black
 3      |   Jack  | Red
```

I need create N number of txt files (based on number of rows) with title as in column Name and content as in column Surname.

For example, based on example above I would like to have 3 files, John.txt (with content "White"), Bill.txt (content Black) and Jack.txt (content Red)

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried to solve this problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using pandas and extracting the values as lists

```
# import and read
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("your_file.xlsx")

# create lists
names = df["name"].values
file_contents = df["surname"].values

# iterate through lists
for name, content in zip(names, file_contents): 
    f = open(f"{name}.txt", "w")
    f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with pylightxl see https://pylightxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

```
import pylightxl as xl

workbook = xl.readxl('yourexcefile.xlsx')

for row in workbook.ws('Sheet1').rows:
    filename = row[2]
    text = row[3]
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(text)
```